# Get md5 checksum of large file in powershell

Tags: powershell

```
Function calculateMD5($filename) {
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($filename)))
$hash = $hash -replace '-', ''

return $hash.ToLower()}
```

I used the above query but getting below error

> Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "The file is
> too long. This operation is currently limited to supporting files less
> than 2 gigabytes in size."

Tried below

```
$hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::Open("$someFilePath",[System.IO.Filemode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)))
```

However I PowerShell stop working using this

Comment: Did you try the [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash?view=powershell-7.1) cmdlet?

Comment: @Vivek Get-FileHash not working

Comment: [`Get-FileHash`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash) is indeed the correct *PowerShell* way to do this (the difference is that PowerShell is hardly using any memory as it *streams* the whole file). Please elaborate on "*not working*"...

Comment: If it helps I just tried `Get-FileHash` on a 3GB file I created with FS util and it worked, understandably slow, but it worked.  I'd point out reading the data into memory often results in memory consumption 4x the size of the read file. [Reference](https://posh-able.com/2020/01/12/powershell-performance-part-2-reading-text-files/). Ordinarily I think memory concerns are overblown, but in this case you probably need to consider it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have commented, in PowerShell you should use the [Get-FileHash](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-filehash) cmdlet:

```
(Get-FileHash -Path $filename -Algorithm MD5).Hash.ToLower()
```

If however you want to do this using .Net methods, I'd suggest you change your function to:

```
function Get-FileMD5 {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType Leaf})]
        [Alias('FileName','FilePath')]
        [string]$Path
    )
    $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.MD5]::Create()
    $stream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($Path, [System.IO.FileMode]::Open, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)

    $result = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($hasher.ComputeHash($stream))
    $stream.Dispose()
    $hasher.Dispose()
    $result.Replace("-","").ToLower()
}
```

The above conforms to the `Verb-Noun` convention in the function's name and internally uses a stream.